# Scrapy: how to output in multiple rows for each data

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I've written a script in python scrapy, to parse some items from price comparison website. I'm not satisfied with result because script stick all results in one row like:

```
price,seller
"4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4","Opinie o ewitaldo.pl,Opinie o dobrazielarnia.pl,Opinie o brokulek.pl,Opinie o delikatesyznatury.pl,Opinie o bialastokrotka.pl,Opinie o aleeko.pl,Opinie o aptekamini.pl,Opinie o farmeko24.pl,Opinie o straganzdrowia.pl,Opinie o bdsklep.pl"
```

and what I need is:

```
price,seller
4,Opinie o ewitaldo.pl
4,Opinie o dobrazielarnia.pl
4,Opinie o brokulek.pl
4,Opinie o delikatesyznatury.pl
4,Opinie o bialastokrotka.pl
4,Opinie o aleeko.pl
4,Opinie o aptekamini.pl
4,Opinie o farmeko24.pl
4,Opinie o straganzdrowia.pl
4,Opinie o bdsklep.pl
```

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from ceneo.items import CeneoItem


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.ceneo.pl/33022301'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)          

    def parse(self, response):
        items = CeneoItem()
        sale_price = response.xpath('(//td[@class="cell-price"] /a/span/span/span[@class="value"]/text())[position() <= 10]').extract()
        seller = response.xpath('(//tr/td/div/ul/li/a[@class="js_product-offer-link"]/text())[position()<=10]').extract()
        items['product_sale_price'] = ''.join(sale_price).strip()
        items['product_seller'] = ''.join(seller).strip()
        yield {'price': sale_price, 'seller': seller}
```

What should be changed to get nice csv output?

Comment: you can iterate the sale_price and seller data then join it as a single list.

Comment: I'm total noob, can you write example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `zip()` to group `price` with `seller` and then `yield` every pair separately

```
def parse(self, response):

    all_prices = response.xpath('(//td[@class="cell-price"] /a/span/span/span[@class="value"]/text())[position() <= 10]').extract()
    all_sellers = response.xpath('(//tr/td/div/ul/li/a[@class="js_product-offer-link"]/text())[position()<=10]').extract()

    for price, seller in zip(all_prices, all_sellers):
        yield {'price': price.strip(), 'seller': seller.strip()}
```

Comment: BTW: full working example I put on github in subfolder [scraping](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)

Comment: Can I ask you for another advice? I want to add another colum to my output with ids of urls I parse. Ids are save in csv with urls (I changed code to use urls from csv).

Comment: if something bigger then create new question - you will have place to put code and error message, and it will be more readable.

Comment: Here is new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993061/how-to-add-new-colum-to-scrapy-output-from-csv

Answer (score -1):

You have the sale_price and seller values.

```
sale_data = [sale_price, seller]
final_list = [zip(*sale_data)[i] for i in xrange(len(sale_price))]
```

this final_list will disply result likes this.

```
[(u'2893', u'Opinie o klimasklep.pl'), (u'2999', u'Opinie o wentsystem.com'), (u'3419', u'Opinie o master.sklep.pl'), (u'2893', u'Opinie o elektrozilla.pl'), (u'2895', u'Opinie o mk.net.pl'), (u'2949', u'Opinie o e-master.pl'), (u'2960', u'Opinie o kajt24.pl'), (u'2999', u'Opinie o klimatop.pl'), (u'2999', u'Opinie o fabryka-komfortu.pl'), (u'3041', u'Opinie o pajm.pl')]
```

Comment: Thanks. How should yield looks like for final_list?

Comment: I try to return and yield final_list but error appear 
 ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'tuple'